# Django - python3.4 virtualenv - apache

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app I've been working on debugging using manage.py runserver.

I'm now attempting to serve it with apache/mod_wsgi.

When I try to open the home page I received a 500 error. The log file shows a syntax error in functools.py.

```
mod_wsgi (pid=28016): Target WSGI script '/home/username/projects/django/testing/testing/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=28016): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/username/projects/django/testing/testing/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/projects/django/testing/testing/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
  from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  from django.utils.version import get_version
File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
  from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 2, in <module>
  from functools import lru_cache
File "/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 291
  cls_or_self, *rest = args
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As far as I can tell that is valid python3.4 syntax. So I'm not entirely sure if I have WSGI configured correctly to use my virtualenv.

```
#testing.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess django.testing.username.vni user=username group=username python-path=/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4/site-packages:/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing/lib/python3.4:/home/username/.virtualenvs/testing
    WSGIProcessGroup django.testing.username.vni

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/projects/django/testing/testing/wsgi.py

    ServerAdmin username@webserver.com
    ServerName django.testing
    ServerAlias www.django.testing

    Alias /static/ /home/username/projects/django/testing/static/

    <Directory />
        AllowOverride None
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/username/projects/django/testing/testing>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/django.testing.log
    LogLevel warn

</VirtualHost>
```

I think I might have a problematic python-path above.

```
#wsgi.py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + "/..")
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

#os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "testing.settings")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm not sure if I've handled the sys.path.append()'s properly or the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. They are as they are to hack around a few other errors I ran into.

Comment: How did you install mod_wsgi? It seems that you are running a 3.4 project with a mod_wsgi compiled for 2.7.

Comment: I think I just `apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi` after a brief search it looks like I should have gotten `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` instead?

Comment: Depending on your distro/version, you may have to compile a 3.3+ Python mod_wsgi. That's what we had to do for CentOS 6.5 / RHEL6 (yes, ugh), because it wasn't available through yum. If the '-py3' version is available as a package, give it a try first.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: how did you see that!? Is there something in the error info that I'm missing, or do you need intuition for that? Thanks a lot, by the way :)

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by Daniel Roseman, the issue was that I had the wrong version of mod_wsgi for python3.4. I removed libapache2-mod-wsgi and installed libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3.

Comment: you are my HERO, i searched sooo long for that (for a different importing problem). Please accept your answer, then it will be easier to find (I suppose, at least^^)